# Someone who buys a lot of books but barely reads them

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What do English speakers call a person who loves to buy and collect a lot of books, but does not often read them?

When purchasing the books, the person might hope to learn new things from the book after reading it in a good opportunity. But they end up leaving the book alone after some reading and probably going for new books. In fact, they seem to be more interested in collecting books than reading them.

Comment: I would probably use "compulsive book buyer".

Comment: If they specifically collect books and don't necessarily read them, they are a book collector. If they buy books and neglect to read them, they are a procrastinator!

Comment: An article in our local paper today about a guy who gave a library of 9,000 medical texts (including an original Darwin *Origin of The Species*) to Mayo Clinic.  He was referred to as a "bibliomaniac".

Comment: Wow @HotLicks that's it :) He certainly didn't read them all!

Comment: (This was out of a collection of around 30,000 books total.  The guy is obviously a bit of a (wealthy) nut.  (And his wife, too -- she is a quilter, if any of you there know what that means.))

Comment: I read a lot, but I find that I buy books faster than I Read them.  But I buy them for interest in the content, not just to have them.  So I am neither a collector nor a procrastinator.  Well, I am a procrastinator in that I put off things in order to read.  :-)

Comment: @HotLicks I hope I understand what quilter means but I am not sure :-)

Comment: Reminds me somewhat of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257367/idiom-for-someone-who-buys-all-the-best-gear-to-do-something-before-they-even-ha

Comment: @JasonStack - It means someone whose house contains three rooms stacked to the ceiling with "fat quarters" of fabric.

Comment: You could call it hoarding, especially if they end up on TLC's Hoarding: Buried Alive.

Comment: That's Tai Lopez, of course.

Comment: How about a **librarian**? ;)

Comment: @JEL you are right. I added the tag "single-word-request" which is probably more consistent with the context of the question.

Comment: A book magpie, a very common breed.

Comment: One word? **me**. I have a shelf full of books related to my profession that I've barely opened. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Consider, ***bibliomaniac***/***bibliomane***

> bibliomania: excessive fondness for acquiring and possessing books [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bibliomania)
>
> bibliomane: one who passionately collects books [Classic Used Books](http://www.classicsusedbooks.com/?p=886)

Comment: I like 'bibliomaniac' better than 'bibliophile' since the suffix '-mania' carries connotations of irrational obsession which might drive someone to possess, *but not read*, books.

Comment: @Silenus There's also "bibliolater," one extremely devoted to books. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bibliolater Not sure they don't read he books they possess, though...

Comment: *Book collector*. Simple.

Comment: *Excessive* fondness for books? Surely a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @TimLymington I don't think *fondness* implies a degree of affection, so I don't see how *excessive* could contradict it. Would you elaborate?

Comment: @talrnu, he means that it's impossible to be overly fond of books, because they're the best things on Earth. :)

Comment: @Marthaª Ah, that explains the breeze that ruffled my hair.

Answer (score 19):

You may be interested in the Japanese word [**tsundoku** 積ん読](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A9%8D%E3%82%93%E8%AA%AD):

> (informal) the act of leaving a book unread after buying it, typically piled up together with other such unread books

Answer (score 13):

**One Word**

One thing or the other, either *a book collector* or *somebody who doesn't read often*, can be found...but both those denotations in one word is a taller order. The closest I could come was

> **bibliotaph**, *n.*
>   One who buries books by keeping them under lock and key.

["bibliotaph, n.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/18650?rskey=NbAjB9&result=65&isAdvanced=false (accessed December 28, 2015).]

One must have books in order to bury them by locking them away, of course, but that's not to say the bibliotaph *loves* to buy and collect books.

**Two or More Words**

Although the OP is a single word request, perhaps a well-formed noun phrase would do. Given the lack of a single word that covers the desired sense, perhaps a noun phrase is necessary. So, I'll suggest a

> somewhat aliterate bibliotaph.

'Aliterate' is not a rare adjective. It is found in, among others, [*American Heritage*, *Collins*, *Random House Kernerman Websters*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aliterate), and the [*OED Online*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/240391?redirectedFrom=aliterate#eid), as well as garnering [about 24,000 hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=aliterate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). The *OED Online* defines the adjective as

> 2. Of a person or group: unwilling to read, although able to do so; disinclined to read.

["aliterate, adj. and n.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/240391?redirectedFrom=aliterate (accessed December 30, 2015).]

As shown, I would use '*somewhat* aliterate', because the sense I understand from the description of the intended use by the OP is less extreme than *entirely* disinclined, and the book collector described is not *unwilling* (other than circumstantially) to read.

'Aliterate' or 'somewhat aliterate' could also be used to good effect with words suggested in other answers than this. For example,

- a somewhat aliterate bibliophile, or
- a somewhat aliterate bibliomane.

**Obsolete and Obscure Words**

An obsolete sense of **bookkeeper** perhaps comes closer:

> †2. A person who hoards books. Obs. rare.
>   ....
>   1788   F. Grose *Classical Dict. Vulgar Tongue* (ed. 2)    Book-keeper, one who never returns borrowed books.
>   1833   *Humourist's Own Bk*. 46   Sir Walter, in lending a book one day to a friend, cautioned him to be punctual in returning it... ‘For though many of my friends are bad arithmeticians, I observe almost all of them to be good book-keepers.’
>   1884   *Harper's Mag.* Nov. 828/1   The old-fashioned book-keeper, who fears his precious books will be hurt by using.

For the sense you requested, see especially the 1884 quote regarding the **bookkeeper**

> ... who fears his precious books will be hurt by using.

["bookkeeper, n.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21437 (accessed December 28, 2015).]

In the region of the entirely obscure, although not obsolete, there is the **uncut** man:

> c. *transf.* Given to collecting ‘uncut’ books.
>   1862   J. H. Burton Bk.-hunter (1882) 19   He was not a black letter man or a tall copyist or *an uncut man*.

This adjective applied to persons by way of the transferred sense draws on the sense of **uncut** applied to books:

> a. Of books: Not having the leaves cut open.

Two camps or schools of thought on the 'cutting' of book leaves exist, though: one maintains an 'uncut' book does not have its *leaves* cut open; the other maintains an 'uncut' book does not have its *margins* reduced.

> b. Not having the margins cut down.

In that sense (sense b), how easily the book may be read is irrelevant; in the other sense (sense a, shown above, manifest in persons as sense c, also shown above), while it is possible to peer down between the uncut leaves, it is quite difficult to read an uncut book.

["unˈcut, adj.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/211145 (accessed December 28, 2015).]

Comment: I wish this answer was split up. I like bookkeeper quite a bit, but much dislike the other options presented.

Answer (score 6):

***[Bibliophile](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bibliophile)*** carries that connotation:

> - A person who collects or has a great love of books.

(ODO)

Answer (score 4):

**Book hoarder.** It implies the person has too many of them, and derives pleasure out of mere possession.  *"Bibliomaniac"* sounds like a maniac, going around stabbing random strangers.

Comment: My thoughts exactly – "hoarder" is a general term understood by many.

Comment: The term "book hoarder" could just as well apply to someone who just can't let go of the books she or he has read, whereas the challenge here is to find a term or phrase that emphasizes acquisition for its own sake.

Comment: Well, the general connotation is there.  It's irrational.  "Bibiiomaniac" sounds like they like to read them.  "Hoarding" is a negative epithet, and that's what is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that "bibliomaniac" has some of the right connotations. But the words we have that are about books specifically don't address the lack of commitment to the books.

I think that lack of commitment is better described by the word ***dilettante*** (the modern American English definition, not the older aristocratic one) or the word ***dabbler***.

Originally, the word dilettante was used to describe members of the aristocracy who took up arts or sciences. Since they presumably had a lot of spare time for these pursuits, the word connoted some expertise. Currently, most people understand the word to mean something like "dabbler," where a person seems to have a wide range of interests, or an interest in a very deep subject, but lacks the commitment to read the literature or do meaningful work related to their interest. If you look at several dictionary and thesaurus entries, you'll see that two conflicting definitions still exist in many of them. For example, Merriam Webster online uses two definitions:

1. an admirer or lover of the arts
2. a person having a superficial interest in an art or a branch of knowledge :  dabbler

So I think there are words that define part of what you're trying to say, but you may have to come up with a multi-word description or a portmanteau to get the whole definition. Maybe something like:

*Bibliottante*: One who collects many books but only dabbles in their content.

It's also worth noting that the thing you're talking about is a known phenomenon, and the subject of some cultural criticism. I've heard and read descriptions of people who keep lots of books for the *appearance* of sophistication or knowledge. A humorous example that has been passed around among Literature and Creative Writing folks I know is [this Onion article](http://www.theonion.com/article/area-man-well-versed-in-first-thirds-of-great-lite-1323).

Answer (score 2):

*bookaholic* conveys the sense of addiction to possession.

In fact, the highest-ranked Urban Dictionary [definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bookaholic)
is as follows:

> someone who keeps buying books to add to a stack of unread books

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We discourage users to post an answer without any research/reference/link that can support it. Please edit your answer after taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Google provides loads of examples: https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22a+bookaholic%22&start=10

Comment: I think it is a great answer. +1)

Answer (score 1):

pompous or grandiose implies behavior like having a bookcase of unread books they are for demonstration purposes only, actual intelligence may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Once it gets to the point that one's children are [drowning in a sea of books](http://wondermark.com/442/), the neologism “**bibliophibian**” may be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Since *bibliokleptomania* is a recognized word (["a morbid tendency to steal books"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/bibliokleptomania)), one could perhaps be forgiven for speaking of *oniobibliomania* rather than the more awkward *biblio-oniomania*.